# Proving Minus euler constant is finite

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

**Question**

prove that $\lim _{n\to \infty} \left(\ln(n)-\sum_{j=1}^n \frac 1j\right)$ exists and is finite.

**Thoughts**

We bounded the expression from above with $\ln \frac {n+1}n+\sum\frac 1{2j^2}$. We need to show that the sequence is an ascending monotone sequence. Is this the right way to do it? We don't really know where to start and how (induction?)

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$w_n=\log(n)-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$$
then the series with general term
$$w_{n}-w_{n-1}=-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}\sim_\infty\frac{1}{2n^2}$$
is convergent so we conclude that the sequence $(w_n)$ is convergent by telescoping.

Answer (score 1):

I like a geometrical approach. $\log n$ is the area under the graph of $y=1/x$ from $x=1$ to $x=n$. On the same graph, erect a rectangle of hieght 1 over the interval $[1,2]$; height $1/2$ over $[2,3]$; and so on, to height $1/(n-1)$ over $[n-1,n]$. The area of the rectangles is $\sum_1^{n-1}(1/m)$. The rectangles exceed the area under $y=1/x$ by a bunch of "curvilinear triangles". Slide those triangles to the left, so they all sit over $[1,2]$. They don't fill the area 1 rectangle there (but they do more than half-fill it), so their area, as $n\to\infty$, approaches something between $1/2$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_1^t 1/s ds=\log(t)$  Thus by the same reasoning as in the comparison test, $\sum_{j=1}^n 1/(j+1)\leq\log(n+1) \leq \sum_{j=1}^n 1/j$.  But the difference between the upper and lower bound is $\sum_{j=1}^n 1/(j(j+1))$.  Thus $\log(n+1) -\sum_{j=1}^n 1/j$ is already a bounded sequence.  But it's also monotone decreasing, as one can also verify by the reasoning of writing the log as the integral.  Thus the limit exists with $\log(n+1)$ in place of $\log(n)$.  But that difference also converges to 0, and a sum of convergent sequences converges to the sum.